# Permission migration from publish_stream to publish_action

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-opengraph

I am wondering if you have a users permission to publish_stream and you want to publish_action from now on does publish_stream cover both or do we need to re-request the users permission?

If so whats the easiest way of detecting wether they have this permission granted etc.

User journey suggestions welcome.

The login system I have in place is users can use with facebook or their account credentials.

But some users sign up without facebook and then connect later. I don't create the session every time they login as I only need the publish_stream permission which works without needing a live user session with facebook to post when the user does specific actions. There is one column in the table which specifies wether the user is connected or not.

Suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

-Stefan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

publish_stream and publish_actions are two separate permissions. publish_stream does not include publish_actions.

To publish actions to the open graph, you will need to get this new permission for new users and for existing users.

You can check the permissions a user has granted your app by GETing /me/permissions from the Graph API.

In the latest version of the permissions dialog, users will have the option to NOT grant publish_stream - its always an optional permission. If the app requests publish_actions, this permission is considered required.

Once Timeline has launched beyond Developer Beta, you should not need to ask for publish_stream. If you want to publish a feed story, use the Feed Dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. Made it nice and clear! Looks like i'm going to have to use the JS sdk as well after all with feed dialog for 1 or 2 areas which may still need it. However I noticed a bug with the PHP SDK and JS SDK in IE 7 where it wouldnt see the session or cookie... any ideas on this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

As of now, publish_stream includes publish_actions permissions.

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/publishing/#publish_stream

> The publish_stream permission is a superset of publish_actions allowing everything that publish_actions allows plus more.

Answer (score 1):

***Publish_stream*** is Deprecated Permissions from v2.2, that's why u can not use, just only ***publish_action*** u can still use,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

regards
[djavalatte.com](http://djavalatte.com)

Answer (score 0):

You must request `publish_stream` as a new permission because the prompt is much different. It is more around "Add to timeline" and a straight up permission.

To know if you have the permission, you can do many things. The easiest is to try and publish and see if it succeeds. but that will skew your metrics in insights. Better is to use the access token info endpoint and check the scopes you have there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using the PHP SDK and I currently have it set up for publish_stream so would I just request the `publish_actions` from now on?

Comment: yes. It will be available to your users once Open Graph leaves beta

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully published actions to the timeline with only the publish_stream permission.  I cannot say if this is will be the case when it is fully launched or if it's only working because of the developer's beta.  We can know for sure once we're 48 hours away from the official launch by checking out the beta tier.  http://developers.facebook.com/support/beta-tier/