# Facebook connect publish_stream no longer being recognized when authorizing app (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app that needs to publish to a users facebook wall. Up until today (February 1st) everything was working ok. Now when a user goes to authorize the app, it only asks for basic permissions and not for the ability to publish to the users wall. I am sending a publish_stream parameter but it seems like it is getting "lost" somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: I´m getting a different HTML page on safari (when not redirecting to the facebook iPhone app). And when I have the facebook iPhone app, the modal view that shows the confirmation UI dismisses immediatly. Related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Single Sign On (SSO) and the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to Publish in the user's wall.

It's a change in Facebook security policy and now using the `publish_stream` won't work anymore.

I suggest you to follow the steps of the new tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590878/permission-migration-from-publish-stream-to-publish-action) to StackOverflow explains the problem of the deprecation of `publish_stream`